# keras model.load_weights error NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

hope someone can help with this, I am trying to train a model base on another pre-trained model, but I keep getting this error.

Thanks in advance.
and happy coding.

Model

```
model = Unet(backbone_name=efficientnetb2, encoder_weights='imagenet',
             input_shape=(256, 256, 3),
             classes=1, activation='sigmoid')
```

```
    model = get_model(
        mparams['backbone'], 
        input_shape=(mparams['img_size'], mparams['img_size'], 3),
        loss_type=mparams['loss'],
        umodel=mparams['umodel'],
        lr=mparams['lr']
    )
    
    # load model
    model = model.load_weights('./models_v24/model_0.hdf5')

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-b3a8ba8f71c6> in <module>
     41             resize=None
     42         )
---> 43         model, history = train_model(PARAMS, n, train_datagen, val_datagen)
     44         plt.plot(history.history['loss'], label='loss')
     45         plt.plot(history.history['val_loss'], label='val_loss')

<ipython-input-17-191deeedc4ed> in train_model(mparams, n_fold, train_datagen, val_datagen)
     53     model = model.load_weights('./models_v24/model_0.hdf5')
     54 
---> 55     history = model.fit(
     56                         train_datagen,
     57                         validation_data=val_datagen,

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fit'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment `# load model` which is not correct. You are just loading weights here, **not the whole model**. This function returns `None` when loading weights in HDF5 format which explains the current error here.

If the model is created, you just need `model.load_weights('./models_v24/model_0.hdf5')`. Then you should be able to fit the model.

```
model = get_model(...)

# load weights
model.load_weights('./models_v24/model_0.hdf5')
```

Also I noticed you did not accept some of the answers in SO. Please take a look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @OscarRangel: I did not down-vote your question, please do not assume to know who has done it.

Comment: @OscarRangel Could you please accept the answer as it solved your problem. (Tick-mark below the voting buttons.)

Comment: Thanks, @Frightera did no know one had to do that.

Answer (score 2):

don't use [model = model.load_weights()]
use [model.load_weights()] direactly